# return rows where column in variable array in php and sql

Tags: php, sql, arrays

I am writing a query that will return records when the value of one of the columns matches any of the elements of an array. If I use a static array it works (see sample):

```
sql = "SELECT *
        FROM tasks
            WHERE
            tasks.type IN ('homework', 'chores', 'laundry')";
```

What if I have an array of tasks that is populated from user input that I want to use from comparison? Like this:

```
$task_list = //declaration and populate the array. I know it works, so I'm skipping it

sql = "SELECT *
            FROM tasks
                WHERE
                tasks.type IN "+$task_list+" ";
```

This gives me an error.
I really am not any good at mixing php with sql and did search for the answer ... maybe I wasn't able to search properly for the right syntax.

For those that want to know, `var_dump($task_list);` prints the following:

```
array(3) { [0]=> string(8) "homework" [1]=> string(6) "chores" [2]=> string(7) "laundry" }
```

Comment: If it works, then why is it broken in the sql? You need to show WHAT you're doing to generate `$task_list`. Whatever you stuff in there that gets stuffed into your query must result in VALID sql. Since you get a syntax error, it's NOT valid sql, and your building code is NOT working properly.

Comment: And note that `+` is mathematical addition in PHP, not string concatenation.

Comment: The code is rather long. I did vardump to check the array content. I could add it to the answer. What is wrong is the way I involve this array in the query.

Comment: it's an array, then you can't just stuff an array into a string. try it sometime. `$x = array(1); $y = $x . 'himom'` and see what you get.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It fails because $task_list is an array, you should do something like this :

```
$task_list_str = sprintf('"%s"', implode('", "', $task_list));
$sql = 'SELECT *
       FROM tasks
       WHERE
           tasks.type IN (' . $task_list_str . ')';
```

It's a bit convoluted, but it stays as close as possible from your code.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you, it did help a lot (it did the job). I really don't program in php or sql and was just helping a friend. However if you have some advice on how to alter the code to make it simple I'd love to learn it.